# Hazelcast sql queries

Tags: java, hazelcast

In normal SQL queries to select the particular field (`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`emp_email`) we use 
`select emp_name from table_name`(to display/fetch only `emp_name`)

In the same way how to do it in hazelcast?

```
static IMap<String, Model)> map = hazelCast.getMap("data");    
map.put(1,(new Model(emp_id,emp_name,emp_email)));    
map.values(new SqlPredicate("data[any].entity_id"));
```

How to select only `emp_name` values in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a Projection in Hazelcast.  What is stored in your map are objects of type Map.Entry; anytime you want to return something other than a Map.Entry, you can create a Projection to transform the Entry into the desired return type.

When you need to do a non-trivial transformation, you can implement custom Projections, but there are built-in Projections you can simply reuse when you're just trying to return a single attribute or a set of attributes from the entry.

So in your case, you can use the built-in singleAttribute projection:

```
Projection empNameProjection = Projection.singleAttribute("emp_name");
```

And then you can use IMap.project to return the projection for all entries, or for entries matching a predicte:

```
Collection<String> names = map.project(empNameProjection, mySqlPredicate);
```

See:
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/#projection-api